# Can't add Gmail account with OAuth

Tags: email, oauth

I'm trying to set up a mail account using OAuth following the instructions [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/civimail/#adding-an-incoming-email-account-for-processing-bounces-andor-email-to-activities) and [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/38845/how-can-i-set-up-an-incoming-email-or-bounce-account-on-gmail-with-oauth/38846#38846).

I've set up OAuth in Administer > System Settings > OAuth:
[image: Screenshot showing confirmed Gmail OAuth connection]

But when I go to Administer > CiviMail > Mail Accounts I still just see the regular Add Mail Account button, not a drop down that allows me to choose and OAuth account:
[image: Screenshot showing Add Mail Account button]

What have I missed?

**Edit:** Drupal 7.82 and CiviCRM 5.43.2.

Comment: I'm able to replicate this on CiviCRM 5.43.2 and Drupal 9

Comment: Using the API4 explorer when I check OAuthProviders I don't see a mailSettingsTemplate -> https://fz-action.fudev.co.nz/civicrm/api4#/explorer/OAuthProvider/get?orderBy=%5B%5B%22name%22,%22ASC%22%5D%5D but I do on a site where this is working.

Comment: I have no experience with the API. In the extensions manager it says API4 is obsolete. Is that related?

Comment: Maybe - api4 was moved into a core extension. I'd uninstall it, then remove the folder where you have the old api4 extension. But it sounds like there's something else too.

Answer (score 3):

I think there was a recent change that broke it. [This patch](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/22169) was added to CiviCRM 5.44+ to fix it.