# Is there a clear step by step guide to setting up oAuth for Gmail?

Tags: civimail, oauth

I'm looking for a step by step guide on how to set up oAuth for Gmail for bounce processing.

I have the oAuth extension installed, and I have a project set up in Google Cloud, but I'm at a loss what next steps are. I am running civiCRM 5.55.0.

I have read the section "Adding an account via OAuth" on : https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/civimail/#adding-an-incoming-email-account-for-processing-bounces-andor-email-to-activities

But Add Mail button doesn't reveal as a dropdown. I see under "OAuth2 Client Administration" in civiCRM the Gmail setting, and that is where I get lost. I have also read "Google Mail (Provider)" on : https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/oauth/

But that is where it falls apart for me as there isn't a step-by-step guide on what to do in Google Cloud.

Is the actual setup process documented anywhere (or perhaps some one has something they can share)?

Comment: There are step by step instructions on this Stack Exchange post: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/38846/12

Answer (score 0):

I think provider-specific details were left out on purpose and just deferred to their own documentation. There are some (maybe out of date) testing notes at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3645#note_76731.

The last time I checked there was a scary looking screen about the app being unverified, but just ignore it.

If you're already set up at google, but not seeing the Add Mail Account on the mail accounts screen, then did you do the steps at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/oauth/#civicrm-client?